# pythonのAnaconda Navigatorが起動しません

Tags: python, python3, windows-10, anaconda

下のようなエラーがでて困っています。調べていろいろやってみたのですがうまくいかず質問することにしました。
ファイルエクスプローラーのなかで直接`C:\Users\keisu\.continuum`と打ってもそのようなファイルは存在しませんと出ました。
何回かアナコンダを入れなおしているのですが同じ下のようなエラーが出ます。
またジュピターノートブックやspiderでも同じようなエラーが出てできません。
しかし、アナコンダプロンプトはなぜか使えます。

```
ナビゲーター エラー
Navigator の起動で予期しないエラーが発生しました

報告
アナコンダ問題トラッカーでこの問題を報告してください

メイン エラー
C:\Users\keisu\.continuum: Access is denied
トレースバック
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\binstar_client\utils\config.py", line 273, in save_config
    os.makedirs(data_dir)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\os.py", line 213, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\os.py", line 223, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\keisu\\.continuum'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\exceptions.py", line 72, in exception_handler
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 146, in start_app
    window = run_app(splash)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 65, in run_app
    window = MainWindow(splash=splash)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\main_window.py", line 166, in __init__
    self.api = AnacondaAPI()
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\anaconda_api.py", line 1534, in AnacondaAPI
    ANACONDA_API = _AnacondaAPI()
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\anaconda_api.py", line 82, in __init__
    self._client_api = ClientAPI(config=self.config)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\client_api.py", line 660, in ClientAPI
    CLIENT_API = _ClientAPI(config=config)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\client_api.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.reload_client()
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\client_api.py", line 325, in reload_client
    client = self._load_binstar_client(url)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\client_api.py", line 357, in _load_binstar_client
    binstar_client.utils.set_config(config)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\binstar_client\utils\config.py", line 283, in set_config
    save_config(data, USER_CONFIG if user else SYSTEM_CONFIG)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\binstar_client\utils\config.py", line 278, in save_config
    raise BinstarError('%s: %s' % (exc.filename, exc.strerror,))
binstar_client.errors.BinstarError: C:\Users\keisu\.continuum: Access is denied
```

パソコンあんまり詳しくないのでよろしくお願いします。

またアナコンダをダウンロードしたときにインストール先のディレクトリを選択する画面が表示されますがその時、自動的に付与されるDestination Folderに入れることができません。代わりに
C:\anacondaに入れているのですがなにか関係ありますか？

Comment: もしかしたら、中途半端なインストール/アンインストールとかそれに加えてJust MeとAll Usersを変えてインストールしたとか、他のPython関連IDEや環境と混ざったとか、色々とやって訳が分からなくなっている感じがします。必要なデータを外付けドライブ等にバックアップしておいて、Windowsをクリーンな状態で再インストールしてから作業した方が良いのでは？ あるいは別のPCを用意するとか？

Comment: ちなみにこんな記事 [Issues launching or initializing - Troubleshooting](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/troubleshooting/#issues-launching-or-initializing), [Access denied error - Troubleshooting](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/troubleshooting/#access-denied-error) を見つけたので試してみると良いかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

同じ経験者です。私は下記のサイトを参照して解決しました。

[WindowsのAnacondaが動作しないときの対処方法とより良いPython環境について](https://codeaid.jp/win-anaconda/)

上記サイトにも書かれていますが、要約を下記に記します。（３点）

1. 通常の方法でAnaconda3とPython3.xをアンインストール
2. 「C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\Python」フォルダを削除
3. 再度Anaconda3をインストール

念のため、アンインストールとインストールの後にはPC再起動をする。